# How can I have multiple Navigations for the same URL paths in Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to add multiple navigations for the same URL path.

my code..

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table


app = dash.Dash()

index_layout = html.Div([
    # represents the URL bar, doesn't render anything
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    
    html.Br(),
    
    dcc.Link(dbc.Button('Page1',
                        color="secondary",
                        className="mr-1",
                        outline=True,
                        style={"width":400,
                        "vertical-align": "middle",
                        }
                        ), href='/page1'),
    html.Br(),html.Br(),html.Br(),html.Br(),html.Br(),
    dcc.Link(dbc.Button("Page2",
                        style={"width":400,
                        "vertical-align": "middle"},
                        color="secondary",
                        className="mr-1",
                        outline=True
                        ), href='/page2'),
    

])


page1_layout = html.H1("Page1")
page2_layout = html.H1("Page2")

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url-nav', refresh=True),

    html.Span(dbc.Nav(
    [
        dbc.NavLink(dbc.NavLink("Page1", href="/page1")),
        dbc.NavLink(dbc.NavLink("Page2", href="/page2")),

    ],

    pills=True,),
     className="ml-auto"
),
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
    html.Center([
    html.H3('DEMO AP',id='title'),
    # content will be rendered in this element
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
    ],),
])



### CALLBACKS

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname="/"):
    
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    triggered_by = ctx.triggered[0].get("prop_id")

    if pathname == "/page1":
        return page1_layout

    elif pathname == "/page2":
        return page2_layout

    else:
        return index_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Button navigations are working fine, but `html.Nav` only works on the very first click, not consistent and not working on the following clicks.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From testing this out the problem seems to be with this line in `index_layout`:

```
dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
```

If you look in the console you will see that a lot of requests are sent constantly when you're on the main page (when `index_layout` is rendered).

When this line is removed your code works as expected.

Working solution:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table


app = dash.Dash()

index_layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                "Page1",
                color="secondary",
                className="mr-1",
                outline=True,
                style={
                    "width": 400,
                    "vertical-align": "middle",
                },
            ),
            href="/page1",
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Link(
            dbc.Button(
                "Page2",
                style={"width": 400, "vertical-align": "middle"},
                color="secondary",
                className="mr-1",
                outline=True,
            ),
            href="/page2",
        ),
    ]
)


page1_layout = html.H1("Page1")
page2_layout = html.H1("Page2")

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url-nav", refresh=True),
        html.Span(
            dbc.Nav(
                [
                    dbc.NavLink(dbc.NavLink("Page1", href="/page1")),
                    dbc.NavLink(dbc.NavLink("Page2", href="/page2")),
                ],
                pills=True,
            ),
            className="ml-auto",
        ),
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=True),
        html.Center(
            [
                html.H3("DEMO AP", id="title"),
                # content will be rendered in this element
                html.Div(id="page-content"),
            ],
        ),
    ]
)


### CALLBACKS


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("page-content", "children"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("url", "pathname")],
)
def display_page(pathname="/"):

    ctx = dash.callback_context
    triggered_by = ctx.triggered[0].get("prop_id")

    if pathname == "/page1":
        return page1_layout

    elif pathname == "/page2":
        return page2_layout

    else:
        return index_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

The problem here I think is that there are two `Location` components rendered at the same time with the same `id` (`url`). This apparently causes the callback to be called constantly and causes inconsistent link behavior.

Comment: Hi, @bas-van-der-linden, actually in the demo code I provided it seems to be working. but in my actuall code,  I get `cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: Can you share more of your actual code so I can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: @pyd Just to let you know that your bounty is going to expire today. The navigation problem is solved with my answer, but if you're still experiencing the other problem you mentioned and share some more code related to that I can take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to approve, I'll approve it now.. I'll add some more code soon, please answer it later