# Dash multiple independent callbacks

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a simple dash app with line chart and radio buttons which serve as a filter.

I created 2 callbacks - first for the url and the second one for the filter. However when I run the app it keeps updating (I suppose calling the second callback in a loop) all the time. It seems these two callbacks are somewhat dependent on each other but I want them to be independent - I need to run the second one only when the radio button (filter) is changed.

Without the first callback everything worked fine.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('page-content', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')]
)
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return '404'
    elif pathname == '/something/my-dashboard':
        return app.layout
    else:
        return '404'

@app.callback(
    Output("main-chart", "figure"), 
    Input("category", "value")
)
def update_graph(category):
    dff = melted[melted["category"] == category]
    fig = create_chart(dff)
    set_style(fig, category)
    return fig
```

EDIT:
Added layout

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [   dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H1(children="My dashboard"),
                        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="main-chart", figure=fig)]),
                    ],
                    className="column1",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dbc.Label("Filter", style={'fontWeight':'bold'}),
                        dcc.RadioItems(
                            id="category",
                            options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in categories],
                            value="Product A",
                            labelStyle={"display": "block"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    className="column2",
                ),
            ],
            className="row",
            id='page-content'
        ),
    ]
)
```

EDIT2 after @BasvanderLinden advice:

```
fig = create_chart(df)
set_style(fig, "Marketing")

app.layout = html.Div(
    [   dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(
            className="row",
            id='page-content'
        ),
    ]
)

dashboard_layout = html.Div(
    [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.H1(children="My dashboard"),
                        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="main-chart", figure=fig)]),
                    ],
                    className="column1",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dbc.Label("Category", style={'fontWeight':'bold'}),
                        dcc.RadioItems(
                            id="category",
                            options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in categories],
                            value="Marketing",
                            labelStyle={"display": "block"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    className="column2",
                ),
            ],
)


@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), [Input("url", "pathname")])
def display_page(pathname):
    print(pathname)
    if pathname == "/":
        return "404"
    elif pathname == "/my-dashboard":
        return dashboard_layout
    else:
        return "404"

@app.callback(
    Output("main-chart", "figure"), 
    Input("category", "value")
)
def update_graph(category):
    dff = df[df["Category"] == category]
    fig = create_chart(dff)
    set_style(fig, category)
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: Could you also include your layout? This sounds similar to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65937293/9098350). Do you have multiple `Location` components or other components that have the same `ids`?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually in your first callback:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('page-content', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')]
)
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return '404'
    elif pathname == '/something/my-dashboard':
        return app.layout
    else:
        return '404'
```

The problem is that you return `app.layout` here.

It's actually really interesting what's happening here. Since `app.layout` covers your whole layout, this means it will include the `Location` component with an id value of `url` as well. So since `app.layout` is appended to the `page-content` div, this means that after appending `app.layout` to the `page-content` div there are now two `Location` components with the same id (`url`). The fact that there is a new `Location` components registered with id `url` results in the callback being triggered again. This all results in the first callback being recursively triggered and appending elements to the dom. You can see this happening if you inspect the elements in the browser.

The solution therefore is to not return `app.layout` in your callback, but to instead abstract a part of your layout and return that in the callback. That is a component that doesn't include a `Location` component in its definition.

So you could abstract the dashboard in its own component something like this:

```
dashboard_layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H1(children="My dashboard"),
                html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="main-chart", figure=fig)]),
            ],
            className="column1",
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                dbc.Label("Filter", style={"fontWeight": "bold"}),
                dcc.RadioItems(
                    id="category",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in categories],
                    value="Product A",
                    labelStyle={"display": "block"},
                ),
            ],
            className="column2",
        ),
    ]
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
        html.Div(
            className="row",
            id="page-content",
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), [Input("url", "pathname")])
def display_page(pathname):
    print(pathname)
    if pathname == "/":
        return "404"
    elif pathname == "/something/my-dashboard":
        return dashboard_layout
    else:
        return "404"
```

Comment: I can not really say I absolutely understand but I tried your code and when loading page I got 2 errors ```ID not found in layout```. I added ```dashboard_layout``` into the app.layout second Div and it got loaded but again - it got stuck in some loop - loading and moving the chart to the right all the time.

Comment: The `id` warnings are not really a problem here, it's because `ids` used in the callback don't exist yet when you're not on the dashboard page. You can supress it in your dash app initialization: `app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding part of your comment here, but you shouldn't add `dashboard_layout` to `app.layout` directly. `dashboard_layout` should be appended in the callback only.

Comment: It is actually dash Error displayed in the browser. There are two of them. One is: ```Attempting to connect a callback Output item to component:
  "main-chart"
but no components with that id exist in the layout.

If you are assigning callbacks to components that are
generated by other callbacks (and therefore not in the
initial layout), you can suppress this exception by setting
`suppress_callback_exceptions=True`.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
  main-chart.figure``` and nothing is displayed (no content)

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment you can suppress those in the initialization of the dash app by setting `suppress_callback_exceptions` to `True`. Look at what the error message is saying and you will see it is exactly the same thing I said.

Comment: My bad, I havent copied the callback. Filters were not working (the second callback) so I added it but when I open the page the chart keeps resizing. Really strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228631/discussion-between-bas-van-der-linden-and-romanzdk).